# Вывод результата выполнения JavaScript на странице

Tags: javascript, node.js

Хотелось бы узнать как выводить результат выполнения javascript кода на экран? Например результат чтобы console.log выводился на экран. Примеры таких систем это встроенные редакторы в обучающих ресурсах типа CodeAcademy, CodeSchool и тп.
Насколько я понял для этого необходимо использовать NodeJs.

Comment: Самый простой способ - нажать F12 в браузере и перейти на вкладку "Консоль". Или вы имели в виду что-то другое?

Comment: вместо `console.log('текст')` Вы можете использовать `alert('текст')`. Вы это имели в виду в вопросе?

Answer (score 2):

Как то так, просто переписываем функцию `console.log`

```js
(function () {
    var logger = document.getElementById('log');
    var old_log = console.log;
    console.log = function (message) {
            logger.innerHTML += message + '<br />';
    }
})();

console.log('test');
console.log('Wow');
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Наверное есть смысл сохранить оригинальную функцию в переменную какую, на случай если надо вернуть назад?

Comment: Добавил в код, спасибо за поправку.

Answer (score 0):

По сути, все, что пишется на саму страницу (в document) - пишется в определенный узел DOM. Самый простой способ этого добиться - просто писать в какой-либо тег.

```
let p = document.querySelector("#p");
p.innerHTML = "Ваш текст";
```

Разумеется, сейчас такие вещи делаются все реже и реже, чаще всего данный функционал реализуют какие-то фреймворки, но, по сути, все они сводятся именно к этому. Хотите вывести что-то на страницу - придется писать в DOM.

И еще про node.js. Node используется не совсем для этого. Node - это движок V8 (который используется в хроме) с прикрученными к нему либами вроде стандартного ввода-вывода и прочего недостающего для нормальной полноценной работы вне браузера. А DOM, насколько мне известно, в Node.js как раз-таки не реализован (вырезан из V8).

Answer (score -1):

Для отображения объектов можно использовать

```
element.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4).replace(/\n/g, '<br/>').replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;')
```